# If cell has value copy to the next column same row vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a macro which will copy any cell in column `A` if that has value in column `B` in the same row, e.g if `A14`=`"zois"` copy `"zois"` to `B14`.

I have this code but most of the times when a blank cell in `A` take a value  not copied in `B`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, [A1]) Is Nothing Then  
    [b1:B100] = [a1:a100].Value 
  End If  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you enter in column **A** will be copied to column **B** *(even blanks!!)*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, intr As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set intr = Intersect(A, Target)
    If intr Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In intr
            r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version will **not** clear the value in column **B** if the value in **A** is cleared:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, intr As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set intr = Intersect(A, Target)
    If intr Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In intr
            If r.Value <> "" Then
                r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

*BE SURE TO DELETE THE OLD VERSION BEFORE INSTALLING THE NEW VERSION.*

Comment: this code work but when a value deleted from a cell in column A deleted also from the cell in B.is like B1=A1.is possible if i delete the values in A don't deleted in B?